# Does the Lunatic Cultist spawn on iPad?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was searching for more answers on the internet. I kept searching, and I found one thing that help me a little. I went back to Terraria and tried it out, but the Lunatic Cultist didn’t spawn. 

Does the Lunatic Cultist spawn on an iPad?

Answer (score 4):

No, he does not. As detailed on the wiki page for the [Lunatic Cultist](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunatic_Cultist), the boss is only available on desktop and console versions of the game. iOS is a mobile version, so he will not spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1.3 mobile update he will spawn, but golem needs to have been defeated first

Answer (score -1):

The Lunatic Cultist will not spawn in Mobile Terraria. He, The Celestial Pillars, and the Moon Lord are not available in Mobile/Fire TV editions of the game. If you want to fight him you can purchase the PC version here: [Terraria on Steam for PC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600/Terraria/), or you could wait for the "One Terraria", or Mobile 1.3 update to come out. (Expected sometime 2018) Getting Console Terraria is also an option. Hope this helps! =D